# How to run gulptask from package.json?

Tags: npm, gulp, jshint

I am trying to run my gulp lint task in my npm script like this, part of the package.json:

```
"lint":"cd somedirectory && npm run gulp-lint"
"gulp":"gulp",
"gulp-lint": "gulp --lint"
```

When I run npm run lint I get this error:

```
missing script : gulp-lint
```

How can I call the gulp task lint?

Comment: Is the missing comma at the end of the first line of your scripts array a mistake while copying, or is it actually also missing in the `package.json` file?

Comment: was that the answer?